# I am trying to get css sticky footer to work

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I have tried to implement css sticky footer on my page but it doesn't seem to be working. the footer is below the content but not sticking to the bottom of the page.
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

you can view the site I am trying ti implement it on live at www.anderskitson.ca/mrskitson2012

Here is my html code, with some taking out for simplicity

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="main" class="row">
     <div class=" twelve columns ">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="11 columns offset-by-one">
        <img src="http://anderskitson.ca/mrskitson2012/wp-content/themes/mrskitson2012/images/kidsDrawings.jpg" alt="Kids Drawings"/>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
<!-- container ends-->
</div>
<div id="footer" ></div>
```

Here is my css declarations

```
.container{position:relative; min-height:100%; }
#main{ overflow:auto; padding-bottom: 300px; }
#footer{ background-image: url('../images/footer.jpg'); height:300px; width:100%; position: relative; margin-top: -300px; clear:both;}
```

Comment: see my answer and try it, if any issues or i am lagging some where then let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the css on line 45 foundation.css

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    height:100%
}
```

See the screen shot on this link: http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/9064/footerpos.jpg

Comment: Thanks so much it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try `bottom:0;min-width:100%;` as part of your CSS

Answer (score 0):

I added `postion:fixed;display:block;min-width:100%;bottom:0;` and it worked out fine. If you are going to be doing this I would probably also make the top of your footer.gif transparent. Or try a .png file with transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML code:

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <p>Your website content here.</p>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">  
       </div>
</body>
```

CSS code:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}     

.container {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: auto !important;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
        }
        .footer, .push {
            height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
        }
```